# How to download videos from Microsoft's Learn site for offline viewing

Tags: video, download, video-streaming

How to download videos from Microsoft's [Learn](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/) site so I can watch the videos offline whilst travelling? For example videos from the following page:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/intro-to-azure-compute/4-containers

I've tried a plethora of online services but all fail. For example the URL of first video on the above page is:

https://www.microsoft.com/videoplayer/embed/RE2yuaq

According to the Chrome developer mode the video downloads in mp4 fragments which may explain why online services such as KeepVid dont work.

Comment: Stream through VLC and save stream to file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Proof]OK Here's the solution:
Open  the page then right click and inspect.

Click on the three dotted menu ... More tools > Network conditions

User Agent > Uncheck Select Automatically

From the dropdown select Android (4.0.2).
Refresh the page
Play the video, click on the three dotted menu inside the video frame and download !!!!

Comment: did this not work for you ????

Comment: Yes, just tried and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only thing worked for me was [this](https://den.dev/blog/download-azure-media-ffmpeg/)

The main idea is to locate the manifest URL.

- Go to developer mode in your browser (ctrl-shift-i)
- Network tab
- Locate manifest URL by filtering
- Copy URL and change `manifest(format=mpd-time-csf)` to `manifest(format=m3u8-aapl-v3)`
- Use [yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp) (or ffmpeg as in the article) to download

Answer (score -1):

download and install IDM Internet Download Manager. Then every video will have a download button...even gif files or flash files plus it is very useful for downloading files if you dont have a very stable internet connection.